# in R Forecasted values

Tags: r, forecasting

I have few questions regarding the forecast time series model in R.

The forecast values which i got for this is::

**Want to take these values: `40,60,67,80,87` as the percentage values.**

So, How to consider Y-axis of the plot in percenatge

```
YrTimeSeries <- c(40,60,67,80,87);

tsValue<-ts(YrTimeSeries,frequency=1,start=2006)
library(forecast)
(forecast(tsValue,h=5))
    Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
2011        86.9993 72.19680 101.8018 64.36083 109.6378
2012        86.9993 66.06645 107.9321 54.98528 119.0133
2013        86.9993 61.36233 112.6363 47.79094 126.2077
2014        86.9993 57.39653 116.6021 41.72576 132.2728
2015        86.9993 53.90256 120.0960 36.38220 137.6164
```

1. The values for Forecasted value(blue line) for each year is same. Can someone please explain me why?
2. The 95 % predictive interval is `(36.38220,137.62)`. What does it infer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The forecast is a flat line since you invoked `forecast()` with its default configuration. This invokes `ets()` (look at `forecast(tsValue,h=5)$method` to see which method was used for forecasting), with a model specified as "ZZZ". `ets()` then tries to find the best model and settles on "ANN": additive error, no trend, no seasonality (see `?ets`), so there is nothing in the model which should cause the forecast to deviate from a flat line. Add some more data and call `ets()` with a trend to see a trend forecast:

```
YrTimeSeries <- c(40,60,67,80,87,100,200,300,400)
tsValue<-ts(YrTimeSeries,frequency=1,start=2006)
forecast(tsValue,h=5,model="AAN")
```

The 95% predictive interval gives you an interval in which 95% of future observations will lie, *assuming that your model is correctly specified*.

EDIT: Vids comments that he would like the forecast to be between 0 and 100 as a percentage. In this case, I would first transform the input data to logits (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit), where I added some data so we get an automatic trend:

```
YrTimeSeries <- c(10,20,30,40,60,67,80,87)
YrTimeSeries.logit <- log((YrTimeSeries/100)/(1-YrTimeSeries/100))
tsValue<-ts(YrTimeSeries.logit,frequency=1,start=2006)
```

After forecasting, we backtransform the mean forecast and prediction interval limits:

```
100*(1/(1+exp(-(forecast(tsValue,h=5)$mean))))
100*(1/(1+exp(-(forecast(tsValue,h=5)$upper))))
100*(1/(1+exp(-(forecast(tsValue,h=5)$lower))))
```

Comment: Note that a flat forecast is often the very best thing to do. Simple forecasts (perhaps even the yet simpler "naive" no-change forecast - extrapolating just the last observation) are often surprisingly hard to beat.

Comment: Thanks Stephan to elaborate. I have another query to be resolved. Kindly help me. I am calculating each value(Y-axis) in percenatge of children took admission in each year.I want the predicted values to in percenatges. Is it possible. I have mentioned my query at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063605/in-r-how-to-make-the-y-axis-values-in-percenatge

Comment: @Vids: I edited the answer - I would first logit transform the data. And changed an error (`ets()` without a specified model looks for the "best" model to explain the data, which for your original data happened to be a model without trend).