# In R how to make the Y-axis values in percenatge

Tags: r

I am plotting time series graph with forecasting. I need to take the Y-axis values as in percentage. How to proceed for this. Please specify.

```
val <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select COUNT(*) from Admission where YEAR(YearOFRegistration)=2006 and YEAR(Admission)=2006); 
Ttl <- sqlQuery(dbhandle, 'select COUNT(*) from Admission where YEAR(YearOFRegistration)=2006');
 firstyr<-(val/Ttl)*100
```

Same way I am calculating for each year.

```
>  YrTimeSeries <- c(firstyrs,secyr,thirdyr,forthyr,fifthyr)
tsValue<-ts(YrTimeSeries,frequency=1,start=2006)
library(forecast)
plot(forecast(tsValue,h=5))
```

**Forecast values are**

```
Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
2011        86.9993 72.19680 101.8018 64.36083 109.6378
2012        86.9993 66.06645 107.9321 54.98528 119.0133
2013        86.9993 61.36233 112.6363 47.79094 126.2077
2014        86.9993 57.39653 116.6021 41.72576 132.2728
2015        86.9993 53.90256 120.0960 36.38220 137.6164
```

I am doing forecasting for next 6 years. I have included 2006 to 2010 years data and calculated in percentages. What I am worried about is I want to take predictive values in percentage of children taken addmision.Please elaborate where I am going wrong.

Comment: @January: Values is in percentage: (Number of children got admission/number of children did registration)*100

Comment: I don't see any "Number of children" in your question. Please elaborate with an example that can be run and tested, with actual output and expected output.

Comment: ...and that includes what you already did.

Comment: @January,@ Paul Hiemstra: I have doing forecasting for next 6 years. I have included 2006 to 2010 years data and calculated in percentages. What I am worried about is that i am getting 101,109 etc as an predictive values.Please elaborate where I am going wrong

Comment: @Vid: so the problem is not one of _plotting_, but one of _constraining the forecast_, which we are discussing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063273/in-r-forecasted-values In this case, it would probably be best to delete or at least close this question.

Answer (score 2):

Just redefine your Y-variable

```
x = sort(rnorm(100))
y = x * 2 + rnorm(100)
plot(x,y, type='b') # plain data
plot(x,y/max(y)*100, type='b') # Y-axis in percentage
```

Comment: One question can evolve faster than many wisemen can answer :)